# Is it fine to mention my 3 years of "internship" experience in my resume?

Tags: resume, career-development

As an intern, I have been working at a IT company for the past three years. This internship gave me a good experience in testing and development of web based applications. Moreover, I have been playing main role in supporting the company's website.

Now, I am in dilemma whether I should add this 3 years internship experience to my resume or not, including that my position in the company was as an 'IT Intern' Also, I mainly worked in the eBusiness Team of the IT Department, should I mention that too?

Comment: Hi @samarasa, overall, this was a good suggested edit! But remember, try to avoid the words "suggestions" or "advice". This makes the question way too open ended and can invite polling, making it hard to vote the best answers to the top since it's not clear what the exact question is. I approved your edit, since it was helpful, but I edited out the suggestions part.

Comment: Hello x76x, I'm curious, why do you think it's not a good idea to add this experience to your resume? Adding this into your post will help clarify the exact problem as you see it so that others can provide more clear solutions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @x76x, again, please add that to your post in an [edit]. On our site, comments are just used to suggest improvements or seek clarification, but you should [edit] your post in the body so people don't miss the info. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you list the internship. As you said *"This internship gave me a good experience in testing and development of web based applications.* That is what you are supposed to use to sell your self to the next employer. The ability to include the internship on a resume, and to network, is why people just starting out take an internship.

If you don't include it on your resume you will either have a hole in your resume, or a resume that shows that you have zero relevant experience.

Don't just list it as a one liner. Treat it like any other job. Tell us what you learned, and what tasks or projects you completed.

If you are still in school they should have a office or a website that can help you prepare a proper resume. Or even have somebody at the internship look it over. Have your supervisor review it, or ask if they can recommend somebody in HR.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't see anything wrong with adding your internship experience to your resume. I think that you are going to finish your studies and now looking for full time jobs.

Better to add your internship experience in terms of projects to the resume. Moreover, clearly explain your role in those projects and list different new technologies you have learnt (e.g., programming languages, source code management, etc.). If it is allowed, you can also provide links to the websites you have worked on.